# Multiple build targets in visual studio C/C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to compile in one fell swoop multiple build targets? For example, I would like to compile an .exe and a static library which includes everything but the .c file that includes main()

If that's not possible, how to manage multiple build targets like this?

Comment: You can build multiple dlls, exes and libs by defining different projects with these outputs. For your specific example, I would make one project that builds the lib, and one that contains main.c that compiles to an exe, and links the aforementioned lib.

Comment: But I can't do like in GNU Make where I can define a .o target and then a .so and ELF which build on top of that?

Comment: Kind of. Your library code can go in a project that has a build target for a .lib(.o) file and for a .dll(.so). You could link the executable to either of those. It is not possible to transform a lib => .dll (.o => .so) directly, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that the link doesn't carry from the static lib to a `.exe` that has the statically lib (say it's everything but `main.cpp`), so now you need to maintain more project files.

Answer (score 6):

You actually can build multiple configurations of the same project. So you need make sure each individual configuration builds okay and in separate path. Then you can use Batch Build dialog to do build all in one time. I hope it should be even possible to build exe and dll using the same project, but different configurations.

[Build multiple configurations simulataneously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651644.aspx):

> - On the menu bar, choose Build, Batch Build.
> - In the Build column, select the check boxes for the configurations in which you want to build a project.
> - Choose the Build or Rebuild buttons to build the project with the configurations that you specified.

For more reference, see the [batch build dialog box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/169az28z(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: If you have Visual Studio in French (like I do), that dialog option is called "Générer en tâche de fond..." (for some reason), just in case you can't find it.